# Noetherian ring of symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian

> I wish to show that $k[x_1,x_2,..,x_n]^{\Sigma_n}$, which is the ring of all symmetric polynomials, is Noetherian.

I thought the easiest way to do this would be to show that every ideal is finitely generated, but I cant seem to get any proof to hold, any help?

Comment: Your question is a particular case of a more general result: if $A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra ($K$ isn't necessarily a field), and $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of $A$, then $A^G$ is also a finitely generated $K$-algebra.

Answer (score 3):

The ring of symmetric polynomials is a polynomial ring generated by elementary symmetric polynomials, hence is Noetherian by Hilbert basis theorem.